# Memory leak in android.os.Message and/or Handler.removeCallback?

Tags: android

I have an activity that looks like the following:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Runnable refreshTimer = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            refresh();
        }
    };

    protected onCreate(...) {
        handler.postAtTime(refreshTimer, ...);
    }

    protected onDestroy() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(refreshTimer);
    }

    protected void refresh() { ... }
}
```

After onDestroy is called, there are still messages in the activity's MessageQueue that contain references to MyActivity$0 (the refresh Runnable) for some reason.  Because MyActivity$0 has an implicit reference to MyActivity, this causes a memory leak of the MyActivity context.

The result of merge_shortest_paths for android.app.Activity excluding phantom,soft,weak,etc references using Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool:
[image]

(The source code above is a simplification of the actual object relationship displayed in the MAT dump)

Shouldn't calling removeCallbacks remove any references to the runnable objects from the Queue? Why am I leaking contexts?

Answer (score 2):

Something to try:

According to the android docs:

[OnDestroy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29):
The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

When you are exiting your activity, it looks like there are still a bunch of queued up messages and the context for unregistering is not invoking the cancel callback.

What you should do is unregister your runnable in [onPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29):
This callback is mostly used for saving any persistent state the activity is editing, to present a "edit in place" model to the user and making sure nothing is lost if there are not enough resources to start the new activity without first killing this one. This is also a good place to do things like stop animations and other things that consume a noticeable amount of CPU in order to make the switch to the next activity as fast as possible, or to close resources that are exclusive access such as the camera.

Typically a Receiver or "Scheduled" Runnable will register in onResume, and unregister in onPause for better lifecycle pairing

Without seeing what you are doing in refresh, it is tough to tell, it could be leaking due to activity references that are activity scoped referenced in the refresh method.